# C++ 11 - Parsing of the following date string "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"

Tags: date, c++11, parsing

I'm using simple method for parsing incoming date strings into "date::sys_seconds" objects:

```
template<typename StringT, typename ResolutionT = date::sys_seconds>
    date::sys_seconds DateTimeToVal(const StringT& s, const StringT& format)
    {
        std::basic_istringstream<typename StringT::value_type> in{ s };
        ResolutionT tp;
        in >> date::parse(format, tp);

        return tp;
    }
```

If the date is as follows: "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000" and I use the following format: "L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" than it works as expected.

But I need to parse date string in the following format: "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" (there is additional "Z" at the end identifying time zone).

Adding additional "Z" at the end of format : "L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you use [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) to fill in a [`std::tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) object from which you can easily get a "POSIX time" (i.e. number of seconds since epoch)? When it comes to dates and times, don't reinvent the wheel, it will usually be done badly (https://thedailywtf.com/ is full of such examples).

Comment: FWIW, I don't think attempting to use `date::parse` constitutes reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Considering that there is no `std::date` class or namespace... Perhaps if the OP meant `std::chrono::sys_seconds` it would be a different matter, but that was introduced in C++20, and this question is tagged `c++11`.

Comment: You could try the format code `%z`, but afaik it is non-standard.